# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, server, client

I create a TCP connection between a server and a client, but after few requests I have this error message :

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'

On this line :
`_clientSocket.Send(buffer,0,buffer.Length,SocketFlags.None);`

How can I resolve this error ?

**Server code**

```
private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
private static List<Socket> _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

    SetupServer();

}

private static void SetupServer()
{
    Log.writeEventLog("Setting up server...");
    _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 100));
    _serverSocket.Listen(1);// max listen client
    _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
}

private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
    _clientSockets.Add(socket);
    Log.writeEventLog("Client connected");
    socket.BeginReceive(_buffer,0,_buffer.Length,SocketFlags.None,new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),socket);
    _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
}

private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
    int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
    byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
    Array.Copy(_buffer,dataBuf,received);

    string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
    Log.writeEventLog("TEXT RECEIVED: " + text);

    string response = string.Empty;

    if(text.ToLower() != "get authentication key")
    {
        response = "Invalid Request";
    }
    else
    {
        response = "TEST";
    }

    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
    socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), null);
    socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
}

private static void SendCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
    socket.EndSend(AR);
}
```

**Client code**

```
private static Socket _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    LoopConnect();
    SendLoop();
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ReadKey();

}  

private static void SendLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a request: ");
        string req = Console.ReadLine();

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
        _clientSocket.Send(buffer,0,buffer.Length,SocketFlags.None);

        var receivedBuffer = new byte[2048];
        int rec = _clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuffer,SocketFlags.None);

        byte[] data = new byte[rec];
        Array.Copy(receivedBuffer, data, rec);
        Console.WriteLine("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
    }
}

private static void LoopConnect()
{
    int attempts = 0;
    while (!_clientSocket.Connected)
    {
        try
        {
            attempts++;
            _clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 100);
        }
        catch (SocketException) {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection attenpts: "+ attempts.ToString());
        }
    }

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

```
socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None,
new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), socket);
```